# QGIS report composer to show related tables

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to include in the QGIS report composer a fields group section with tables that are related on a 1 to many relationship?
For example a point layer "HOUSES", with a KEY that relates to a table "FAM" that has a list of family members data (name, sex, age , etc). But I can´t get it to work in qgis report composer.

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: What did u do so far ? Where is the "blocking point" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an Attribute table and use a filter expression to get to corresponding data.
If you have an Attlas/Group Layer with the column "key", and you want to get the table fam that also has the column "key", the item properties of the attribute table would look like that:

[image]

Comment: Hi @nepluisse I have used your approach but no success, my tables look like the file in attachement

Comment: @CarlosRivas Your expression has the `@atlas_featureid` variable where it should have the `@atlas_feature` variable.

Comment: Solve! Thank you very much